# Как скрыть QPainter по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt5, qpainter

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне скрыть рисунок от `QPainter` по нажатию на кнопку.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtQuick
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsView
import sys

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(100, 250, 250), 1, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setBrush(QColor(250, 250, 250))
        painter.drawRect(90, 110, 340, 280)

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        self.setFixedSize(1300, 800)
        self.setUpdatesEnabled(True)
        self.setObjectName("main")

        self.Button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.Button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 305, 115, 30))
        self.Button1.setText("OK")
        self.Button1.clicked.connect(self.button1_click)

    def button1_click():
        painter.hide()


def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант. Нажмите несколько раз на кнопку.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QBrush, QPen, QColor
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QRect
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QPushButton, QMainWindow, QApplication


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.button_1 = QPushButton("OK", self, clicked=self.button1_click)
        self.button_1.setGeometry(QRect(110, 305, 115, 30))

        self.flagPaintEvent = True                               # +

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        if self.flagPaintEvent:                                  # +
            painter = QPainter(self)
            painter.setPen(QPen(QColor(100, 250, 250), 1, Qt.SolidLine))
            painter.setBrush(QColor(250, 250, 250))
            painter.drawRect(90, 110, 340, 280)

    def button1_click(self):                                     # + self
        self.flagPaintEvent = not self.flagPaintEvent            # +
        self.update()                                            # +


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    main.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
    main.setFixedSize(1300, 800)    
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ничего не происходит

Comment: @whyeaye вы скопировали мой пример, запустили его, нажимаете на кнопку и ничего не происходит?

Comment: не хватало self.update() на 22 строчке

Comment: если у меня будет несколько фигур, которые должны реагировать на разные кнопки, (скажем первая кнопка убирает первую фигуру, вторая вторую) должен ли я создавать несколько флагов и прописывать фигуры в  paintevent?